# Prove the law of cosines for an obtuse angle

Tags: trigonometry

The question that I am pondering is that I need to derive the law of cosines for a case in which angle A is an obtuse angle.

Comment: A good start would be to include in your question a proof that is good when angles $A$ and $B$ are both acute, and describe what happens if you make $A$ obtuse. Then at least you could say what specific problem(s) you encountered while attempting the proof.

Answer (score 1):

Take for example the obtuse triangle

[image]

Beginning with the angle in blue (the obtuse one) and counterclockwise, call the vertices $\;A,B,C\;$, and call $\;D\;$ where the straight angle is. If we call $\;\alpha\;$ the blue angle, we then  have by Pythagoras

$$AC^2=CD^2+AD^2$$

And on the triangle $\;\Delta CDB\;$, again by Pythagoras:

$$BC^2=BD^2+CD^2\implies BC^2=BD^2+AC^2-AD^2=$$

$$=AC^2+\overbrace{(BD-AD)}^{=AB}\overbrace{(BD+AD)}^{=2AD+AB=2AC\cos(180-\alpha)+AB}=$$

$$=AC^2+AB(-2AC\cos\alpha+AB)=AC^2+AB^2-2AC\cdot AB\cos\alpha$$

Answer (score 0):

Draw out your generic obtuse triangle.  Drop the altitude to the extended base line.
Lets make B the base, and A the line to the vertex.  The extension of the base line = $A \cos (180-\theta) = -A \cos \theta$
the extended base  = $B - A \cos \theta$
the altitude = $A \sin \theta$

$C^2 = (B - A \cos \theta)^2 + (A \sin \theta)^2$

Multiply that out and see if you don't get the equation you are supposed to.